# How to compile ocaml graphics windows cygwin

Tags: graphics, compiler-errors, ocaml

I use cygwin 64 terminal on Windows and want to compile this ocaml graphics code. 
It's saved as a .ml type:

```
let etat x y c=draw_circle x y 10 ;let a=(x-5) and b=(y-5) in moveto a b ;let s=string_of_int c in draw_string s;;
etat 100 100 1;;
etat 200 200 3;;
```

I'm confused between : load graphics.cma open Graphics Graphics.open_graph

And should I use ocamlc -o g graphics.cma g.ml
to compile?

Comment: use ocamlbuild to build your project : ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg graphics <project_name>.native . It will resolve the dependencies. It will link against graphics.cma ; in your code you need to reference the functions of that module either by opening this module, or explicit the namespace by prefixing the functions with Graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'm confued between : load graphics.cma open Graphics Graphics.open_graph

- `load` is a directive of the interactive toplevel. It is not part of the OCaml language. You are using directives to command the interactive toplevel. And it is used to load code to the toplevel.
- `open Graphics` is a language construct that will bring names of definitions in module Graph to the current scope. This allows you to write `open_graph` instead of `Graphics.open_graph`. It is better not to open too many modules (if any) as it may pollute your namespace, and make your code less understandable.
- `Graphics.open_graph` is a function, that, when invoked, will open a graphics window in your machine.

> and should i use ocamlc -o g graphics.cma g.ml to compile.

Yep, you can use `ocamlc` to compile your code. The OCaml compiler toolchain is rather difficult to use. However, there is a compilation manager, called ocamlbuild, that should work like magic, e.g.,

```
 ocamlbuild -pkg graphics g.byte
```

You will get a `g.byte` executable that you can run.